# How to simulate DOS attacks using DARPA dataset or pcap files?

Tags: dataset, dos, pcap, simulate, denial-of-service

I am working on my master's thesis which is about XML-HTTP DOS attacks.
I have some pcap files and DARPA dataset but I don't know how to use them to simulate DOS attacks ?
I used Wireshark to open files and it works but it shows just information.
Do I need to write a program to apply these datasets? Or  already exist some tools ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example of C code used to read in a pcap file (as output by tcpdump or wireshark) with the pcap library.   This code is only tested to work on my system (OS X 10.5 and gcc), so let me know if it doesn’t work on yours.

To use: install the pcap libraries on your system and compile with the “-lpcap” switch.  For this program the command line arguments are a list of pcap files to read in.  The program keeps track of simple byte counts and traffic volume, but illustrates the use of pcap_next and how to access the data in the packet (in this case to get at the IP header).

try this:

http://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~ee122/fa07/projects/p2files/packet_parser.c

or this:

http://code.google.com/p/pcapsctpspliter/issues/detail?id=6